# Same slide multiple times in the presentation sequence

Tags: impress.js

I'm trying to navigate to the same slide multiple times using `impress.js`.

Imagine the following slides:

```
<div id="impress">
    <div id="map" class="step" data-scale="70">
        <img src="img/foo.jpg" class="map" />
    </div>
    <div id="cityX" class="step" data-x="11000" data-y="12000">
        <img src="img/cityX.jpg" class="pic" />
    </div>
    <!-- XXXXXXX TODO show map again-->

    <div id="cityY" class="step" data-x="12000" data-y="12000">
        <img src="img/cityY.jpg" class="pic" />
    </div>
```

My goal is to navigate to `map` slide in the beginning as well as between slides `cityX` and `cityY`. (In fact the map is outline view of the presentation and I want to zoom in to particular city, zoom out to map and zoom in to another city afterwards.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/impress/impress.js/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md), you can programmatically navigate to target slide in Javascript.

In this case, you listened event when the slide moved to next slide. If current slide is `cityX`, move back to slide `map`

However, to avoid moving slide between `map` and `cityX` eternity, you must define a queue of slide IDs that `map` will move to next

```js
var api = impress();
api.init();

const rootElement = document.getElementById( "impress" );
const mapElement = document.getElementById( "map" );
const nextMapSlides = ["cityX", "cityY"];

rootElement.addEventListener( "impress:stepleave", function(event) {
  const currentStep = event.target;
  const nextStep = event.detail.next;

  if (currentStep.id === "cityX") {
    return api.goto(mapElement);
  }

  if (currentStep.id === "map" && nextMapSlides.length) {
    const nextEl = document.getElementById(nextMapSlides[0]);
    api.goto(nextEl);
    // remove from queue
    nextMapSlides.shift();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, as an alternative to `javascript` based solution, following works for me as well:

```
<div id="impress">
    <div id="map1" class="step" data-scale="70" data-x="0" data-y="0">
        <img src="img/foo.jpg" class="map" />
    </div>
    <div id="cityX" class="step" data-x="11000" data-y="12000">
        <img src="img/cityX.jpg" class="pic" />
    </div>
    <div id="map2" class="step" data-scale="70" data-x="0" data-y="0">
        <img src="img/foo.jpg" class="map" />
    </div>

    <div id="cityY" class="step" data-x="12000" data-y="12000">
        <img src="img/cityY.jpg" class="pic" />
    </div>
```

just had to make sure to use `data-x` as well as `data-y` attributes and duplicate the slide multiple times (with different `id`s: `map1` and `map2`).